# How do I align my border animation in the center with the text

Tags: css, animation, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, responsive

I'm using this border animation https://codepen.io/FlorinCornea/pen/KKpvRYo but I'm trying to make it responsive by wrapping it in bootstrap however now its sticking to the left and I cant seem to center it

This is my DEMO:

```css
.circle-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 55px;
  top: 55px;
  left: 55px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.circle {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 2.5px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  animation: spin 10s linear infinite;
}

.circle-wrapper:active .circle {
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

.success {
  background-color: #2e3192;
  border: 2.5px dashed #2e3192;
}

.error {
  background-color: #CA0B00;
  border: 2.5px dashed #CA0B00;
}

.warning {
  background-color: #F0D500;
  border: 2.5px dashed #F0D500;
}

@keyframes spin { 
  100% { 
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

.page-wrapper {
  background-color: #eee;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=6.0" type="text/css" media="all">

<div class="our-process center-align tinted-bg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>Our Process</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="page-wrapper d-md-flex">
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
        <div class="circle-wrapper mx-auto">
            <div class="success circle"></div>
            <div class="icon">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5>Assessor's Visit</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
        <div class="circle-wrapper mx-auto">
            <div class="success circle"></div>
            <div class="icon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5>Surveyor's Visit</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
        <div class="circle-wrapper mx-auto">
            <div class="success circle"></div>
            <div class="icon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5>installation</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
        <div class="circle-wrapper mx-auto">
            <div class="success circle"></div>
            <div class="icon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5>Post Inspection Visit</h5>
    </div>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have bootstrap linked to my site so that's not the issue

Here's an image of what it looks like now i am trying to center align the blue circles with the text that's below them:
[image]

Comment: Do you want it like this? https://nimb.ws/KQReXp

Comment: It doesn't look like it I've edited the description and added a picture I basically want the blue circles center aligned with the text below

Comment: But that's not the output in your code. Complete it.

Comment: @m4n0 he said: _Here's an image of what it looks like now i am trying to center align the blue circles with the text that's below them_ I don't get what else do you want from him ?

Comment: @MaxiGui He updated only now. This is how his code output is: https://nimb.ws/imH1NA even full screen. Different from the screenshot he has posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For Bootstrap 4:

As you use bootstrap, I add 3 bootstrap classes:

- `d-md-flex` (= display:flex on medium screen) on your `page-wrapper`
- `text-center` on your `col-md-3`
- `mx-center` (= margin horizontal auto) on your `circle-wrapper`

The `d-md-flex` could be replace by `row mx-0`

### For bootstrap 3:

You just need to create the missing css classes:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .d-md-flex {
      display: -webkit-box!important;
      display: -ms-flexbox!important;
      display: flex!important;
  }
}
.mx-auto{
  margin-right:auto !important;
  margin-left:auto !important;
}
```

Check that on large screen and it should be centered.

```css
.circle-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 55px;
  top: 55px;
  left: 55px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.circle {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 2.5px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  animation: spin 10s linear infinite;
}

.circle-wrapper:active .circle {
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

.success {
  background-color: #2e3192;
  border: 2.5px dashed #2e3192;
}

.error {
  background-color: #CA0B00;
  border: 2.5px dashed #CA0B00;
}

.warning {
  background-color: #F0D500;
  border: 2.5px dashed #F0D500;
}

@keyframes spin { 
  100% { 
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

.page-wrapper {
  background-color: #eee;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
/************************************/
/**     BOOTSTRAP 4 CSS ADDED      **/
/************************************/
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .d-md-flex {
      display: -webkit-box!important;
      display: -ms-flexbox!important;
      display: flex!important;
  }
}
.mx-auto{
  margin-right:auto !important;
  margin-left:auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-6MXa8B6uaO18Hid6blRMetEIoPqHf7Ux1tnyIQdpt9qI5OACx7C+O3IVTr98vwGnlcg0LOLa02i9Y1HpVhlfiw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="page-wrapper d-md-flex">
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
        <div class="circle-wrapper mx-auto">
            <div class="success circle"></div>
            <div class="icon">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5>Assessor's Visit</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
        <div class="circle-wrapper mx-auto">
            <div class="success circle"></div>
            <div class="icon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5>Surveyor's Visit</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
        <div class="circle-wrapper mx-auto">
            <div class="success circle"></div>
            <div class="icon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5>installation</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
        <div class="circle-wrapper mx-auto">
            <div class="success circle"></div>
            <div class="icon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5>Post Inspection Visit</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the site is run on bootstrap3 and it would take alot of time i don't have to rebuild sliders and navigation do you have a solution in bootstrap 3

Comment: @MaxiGui Do you now understand why I asked him to complete the code?

Comment: sorry mate been out of the game for a little while trying to find my feet again

Comment: @crad98 I edited the demo, you only need to create the missing classes that existed in bootstrap 4 or above in your css